# How to have dependent parameters in JENKINS

Tags: jenkins

Does Jenkins support (out of the box plugin) to have a way of defining dependent parameters. For ex: If I have three fields in a choice parameter for user to input, and if I select option A (considering it gives you a list of options) in the first field, then only other dependent fields should be shown to user to fill out(while doing the build), Similarly if user selects B , it should show rest of the other relevant options

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do a basic if/then on a source parameter using an Active Choice Reactive Reference parameter. This does not solve the problem of not wanting parameters to display or not though.

How to do an if / then on a build parameter, setting another build parameter
============================================================================
**You need the "Active Choices" plugin for starters**.
1) The source parameter
   Create a typical choice parameter - We'll call it "Choose", and give it the choices "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"
2) The derived parameter
   Create an "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter".
   Name: What you want the parameter to be called / referenced as
   Check "Groovy script"
   The script:

```
if (Choose.equals("val1")) {
   return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"Something because we chose val1\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
} else if (Choose.equals("val2")) {
   return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"Something because we chose val2\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
} else if (Choose.equals("val3")) {
   return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"Something because we chose val3\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
} else if (Choose.equals("val4")) {
   return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"Something because we chose val4\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
}
```

**Choice type**:
 Formatted hidden HTML
                -- or --
                Formatted HTML - For testing so you can see the parameter being set

Referenced parameters: The name of the source parameter - "Choose"

Comment: I'm not sure about that one, hopefully someone else will comment. I've not had to take things that far with Jenkins myself. If it's not doable, maybe you could read the contents of a file as input based on a selection, or also look into the EnvInject plugin.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to define values for a list of parameters(already created in the job configuration) based on the values defined for the choice parameter. Like in the above for ex: 


    if (Choose.equals("ON")) 
    {
    string parameter value1=(prompt user to input a value) 
    string parameter value2=(prompt user to input a value)
    string parameter value3=(prompt user to input a value)
    }
    else if (Choose.equals("OFF")) 
    {
    string parameter value4=(prompt user to input a value)
    }