# How to put condition in extensible choice

Tags: jenkins

Hi I have recently started learning jenkins. I would like to know 
how to put a condition for the extensible choice.

I have
Extensible Choice:
Name: DB
Description: DB to load for option 1 and 2
            File1
                File2
                File3
Choice Provider: Textarea Choice Parameter
Choices:    File1
                File2
                File3
Default Choice : File1
When the OS is Linux it should choose the File1 and when it is Unix it should choose File2

Since the default choice is given as File1 it is taking the same File1 for both OS versions. Is there a way that I can put condition for this type of scenario

I want to choose a file which is related to that particular OS

Comment: A screen shot of your setup would be helpful here

Comment: This previous answer may be helpful too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889938/how-to-have-dependent-parameters-in-jenkins/54890147#54890147

Comment: you mean the configuration part which i have mentioned or the complete configuration?

Comment: Just the part that you mentioned, but take a look at the link above and see if that can help.

Comment: I tried but i was not able to add. went through the link which you gave but that is not actually helping me. is there any other way if you have any idea. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything else, maybe someone else will respond